# Linearlayout and text with app:autoSizeTextType=uniform and Lollipop

Tags: android, android-appcompat

im trying to build a keypad in 4 rows and splitted equally thru columns and using autoTextSizetype

`app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"`

something is broken in android 5.0 i guess:

this is the preview in the android studio:

[image]

real world android 5.0:

[image]

obs: android 7.0 it works normally :|

this kind of legacy thing make me crazy

my .xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:padding="@dimen/_8ssp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button_selector_cinza"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="1" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button_selector_cinza"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="2"
                app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:padding="@dimen/_8ssp"

                />


            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button_selector_cinza"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="3"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:padding="@dimen/_8ssp"
                />


        </LinearLayout>




        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_4"
                app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:padding="@dimen/_8ssp"
                android:text="4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button_selector_cinza"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"/>


            <!--Button 5-->

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_5"
                app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:padding="@dimen/_8ssp"
                android:text="5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button_selector_cinza"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"/>


            <!--Button 6-->

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_6"
                app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:padding="@dimen/_8ssp"
                android:text="6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button_selector_cinza"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_7"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:padding="@dimen/_8ssp"
            android:text="7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector_cinza"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"/>



        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_8"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:padding="@dimen/_8ssp"
            android:text="8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector_cinza"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"/>


        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_9"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:padding="@dimen/_8ssp"
            android:text="9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector_cinza"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_apagar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector_cinza"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/keypad_apagar"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:padding="@dimen/_8ssp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp" />


        <!--Button 0-->

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector_cinza"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:padding="@dimen/_8ssp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp" />



        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_ok"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector_cinza"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="OK"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:padding="@dimen/_8ssp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: testing using pure constraint layout and guidelines to see if it solves

Answer (score 0):

fixed using pure constraint layout + guidelines

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector_cinza"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/_8ssp"
        android:text="1"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector_cinza"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"

        android:padding="@dimen/_8ssp"
        android:text="2"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector_cinza"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/_8ssp"
        android:text="3"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.33" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.66"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector_cinza"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/_8ssp"
        android:text="4"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline6" />


    <!--Button 5-->

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector_cinza"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/_8ssp"
        android:text="5"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline6" />


    <!--Button 6-->

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector_cinza"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/_8ssp"
        android:text="6"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline6" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector_cinza"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/_8ssp"
        android:text="7"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline8" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_8"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector_cinza"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/_8ssp"
        android:text="8"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline8" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_9"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector_cinza"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/_8ssp"
        android:text="9"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline8" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_apagar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector_cinza"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/_8ssp"
        android:text="@string/keypad_apagar"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline9" />


    <!--Button 0-->

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_0"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector_cinza"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/_8ssp"
        android:text="0"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline9" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_ok"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector_cinza"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/_8ssp"
        android:text="OK"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline9" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```